# Understanding work case of directional antenna

Tags: signal, antenna, transmission

I try to understanding the workflow of directional antennas.

I want to implement a bluetooth communication with external, directional antenna. Lets suppose that I buy this:

https://cdn3.bigcommerce.com/s-blpsc02m/products/1667/images/1947/A2D5w__15836.1454272603.1280.1280.jpg?c=2

My question is, if this antenna "looks" to the north (the white head looks to north and the back with cable looks to south) . If I transmitted signal from south to north, does the antenna recieve the transmitted signal ?

Comment: Buy one that has a proper data sheet. Posting a picture of an antenna does not mean it's radiating field pattern is immediately clear especially if it has a white circular cover over it.

Comment: do you mean something like this or more detailed(i cant find it) ? https://www.buerklin.com/medias/sys_master/download/download/hf7/h2f/8893370269726.pdf

Comment: If your changing the power level by adding the antenna, your probably violating the spec and FCC laws.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Antennas follow a property called reciprocity. This means that if the majority of the directivity is in one direction during transmit, during receive the directivity will be the same and in the same direction.

So in the case of the PDF you posted for the LogiLink antenna, you can see the it is directive in one direction (for both transmit and receive). If you try to pick up a signal coming from the opposite direction, the signal will be highly attenuated. This means you may or may not receive the signal but you would certainly have a much better chance by pointing the antenna in the direction of the desired signal.

There are also omnidirectional antennas that exhibit gain. These may be more suitable for you if you need to receive signals approaching the antenna from various directions. An omnidirectional antenna exhibits gain by restricting the pattern in the vertical orientation.

Comment: please take a look at this image. https://prnt.sc/fobm3a .I mean that if antenna 1 transmitt, antenna 2 will recieve the signal ? Ι want directional to avoid the receiveing from side objects

Comment: i dont want to receiving from various directions

Comment: The antenna you have pictured is highly directional. Signals coming from the back side will be greatly attenuated. Generally speaking this is not effective.

Comment: Yes.this is what i want. I want to avoid the signals coming from the antenna 1. It can be happen ? Dont see the antenna only in the picture. Its for example. See the antenna at first link, or the pdf of the comments on the top

Comment: It will greatly attenuate it but there is not sufficient information to determine if the receiver on antenna 2 will detect it. For this, you should examine the Friis formula.

Comment: take an another look, pleasssse 

https://prnt.sc/fociy8 . I want this, if directional antenna 3 , avoid the signal of 1. I want to know if this can achieved

Comment: What you are picturing is the ideal state. In practice, antennas still receive some signal from the "wrong direction". It depends on how close the other antenna is, how much gain it has, the power of the transmitter, and the sensitivity of the receiver. All of these go into the Friis formula. But as I stated previously, you do not have enough information to make this determination.